# group by ID and select the value that doesn't contain a substring

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df in pyspark that contains IDs and location codes. My problem is that some IDs duplicate and contain a row of information I want to ignore.

For Example

```
ID             Location code

1              Legacy _ Location
1              Keep this row
2              L-Location
2              Keep this row too
```

In this toy example, I want to discard the rows from each ID that contain either `Legacy` or `L-*`

I've tried to build my own function called `filterLoc` and then use `df.groupby(ID).apply(lambda x: filterLoc(x))` but I get an error about `Invalid udf: the udf argument must be a pandas_udf of type GROUPED_MAP.`

filterLoc is defined as:

```
 def filterLoc (df):
  if len(df)==1:
    return(df)
  else:
    x = df[~df['Location Code'].str.contains('L-*|LEGACY')]
    return(x)
```

My goal would be to end up with the follow df.

```
ID             Location code

1              Keep this row
2              Keep this row too
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just do

```
df2 = df.filter(~df['Location Code'].rlike('L-*|LEGACY'))

df2.show()
+---+-----------------+
| ID|    Location code|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|    Keep this row|
|  2|Keep this row too|
+---+-----------------+
```

Though this does not correspond exactly to the UDF. In case there is only 1 location code in that ID, and you want to keep those even if they contain legacy, you can do

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'count_id', 
    F.count('ID').over(Window.partitionBy('ID'))
).filter(
    "count_id = 1 or not `Location Code` rlike 'L-*|LEGACY'"
).drop('count_id')
```

And if you really prefer to use pandas, use `applyInPandas`:

```
def filterLoc(df):
  if len(df)==1:
    return(df)
  else:
    x = df[~df['Location code'].str.contains('L-*|LEGACY')]
    return(x)

df2 = df.groupBy('ID').applyInPandas(filterLoc, df.schema)
```

Comment: I like the second approach with the SQL-like statement in the filter(). Let's say I have another column to add to Location Code (call it Location Code 2). Same filtering parameters but it's just over two columns now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`, partition by `ID` and order by `case/when` clause:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(
    F.when(F.col("Location code").rlike("L-*|LEGACY"), 0).otherwise(1).desc()
)

df1 = df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(w)) \
    .filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

df1.show()

+---+-----------------+
| ID|    Location code|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|    Keep this row|
|  2|Keep this row too|
+---+-----------------+
```